# Changed color in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, photoshop, gamma, srgb

Why does an image imported from Photoshop to Unity change its colors?

[image: Link to image]

Both programs being set to sRGB mode and gamma correction at `Project Settings>Player>Other Settings>Rendering>Color Space` are set to `Linear` or even `Gamma` does not matter.

I formatted the C drive and reinstalled Unity from scratch, but it didn't help.

[The colors of 3D objects are also changing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfZp8.png)

Comment: What colour compression have you get the image set to?

Comment: The color difference you are getting in unity and blender is due to the fact that they both uses different renderer and are rendering the objects differently.

Answer (score 0):

When I reset the settings in "Project Settings/Player", it changes from linear to gamma and then the colors are fixed. My question is why can't I have linear like everyone else? The quality is still poor despite the settings in the inspector quality set to "none".